# Terminal stops running commands after switching Node's version with nvm

Tags: javascript, terminal, nvm

Hope to find you guys well =).

So, my problem is that I'm trying to initialize a Gatsby project and after some trouble I discovered that for some boiler plate "starter" template to work I would have to install an older version of Node. Since I already have nvm installed, I just downloaded the version I wanted and switched via terminal.

I verified it with node -v and it threw me the version I wanted. The thing is that when I try to run 'gatsby develop' it says "gatsby: command not found".

And that if I close and open my terminal again it resets the version. Is this supposed to behave like that?

By the way, you can already tell that I'm new at this so any information or guidelines will be of extreme helpfulness.

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing `yarn develop` if using yarn. Or `npx develop` if using npx

Comment: I've tried npx developed and it installed npx but didn't found the 'develop' command. I'm trying to see what happens if I reinstall Gatsby's CLI inside this terminal.
Looks like this switched terminal can't access my "globally installed commands" is that's a thing. lol

Comment: Do this could possibly mean that I have to "configure" every Node version I install?